# Is using eval together with argparse save?

Tags: python, logging, argparse

I use argparse and eval to change loglevels of logging.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Adds New Location to the Snipe-IT Server")
parser.add_argument('-l', '--loglevel', type=str, default='WARNING', choices=['DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL'])
args = parser.parse_args()
logging.basicConfig(level=eval(f"logging.{args.loglevel}"))
```

I wonder if it is save to use eval in this case? I don't know if choices limit in this case the inputs.

Comment: Short answer no :D eval is nearly never safe, maybe safer is going to be getattr in your usecase

Comment: Given that you used a whitelist, this is technically save. However, it is still not good. Instead, use a dict to map the strings ('DEBUG', 'INFO', ...) to the constants (logging.DEBUG, logging.INFO, ...), i.e. `d = {'DEBUG': logging.DEBUG, 'INFO': logging.INFO, ...}`. Then set the logging level with `level=d[args.loglevel]`.

Comment: @NicolasForstner This introduces needless duplication. `getattr` is a better solution

Comment: Nice this was actually my thinking. I usally tend to never use eval, because given reasons and used recently ast.literal_eval, which is not working obviously in this case. Thats why I really like this plattform.

Comment: @DeepSpace, no, just use `choices=d.keys()`

Comment: @Nicolas Forstner also if using choices=d.keys() the dict already duplicates all the `logging.` calls where I only need one with `getattr`. Still appreciate your comment.

Comment: @MaKaNu Oh, I thought you meant the duplication in the choices array. You are right though, there is some redundancy in `d` that could be avoided. I do however like the flexibility from renaming the loglevels, e.g. `d={'low': logging.Debug, 'medium': logging.INFO, ...}`

Comment: @ Nicolas Forstner I tempt to use `logging.getEffectiveLevel()`  to ensure the actuall Loglevel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not quite safe. It won't be too hard for a knowledgable malicious user to hack the `argparse` module to be able to pass any thing they want through the CLI.

However, at this point they might as well just write their own malicious program than trying to use yours as an attack vector.

Even if one deems this very specific usage of `eval` safe**r** because its input is validated, knowingly using a function that exposes a huge attack surface when a safe and easy alternative is available (`getattr` in this case) is a very questionable decision.

Moreover, the codebase might change in the future (eg. the sanitization code might be removed or modified) leaving the `eval` usage more vulnerable than it already was.

Regardless, just use `getattr`. `eval` is almost never the correct solution.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=getattr(logging, args.loglevel))
```

Comment: The OP implementation is quite safe. I don't see any problem with it. People freak out about eval all the time but if well used, it is not that dangerous. As you say, you should hack the argparse module, but once you hack a module you can do basically anything when that module is imported, you don't need an eval as entry point. Said that, I agree your solution is good, it is more elegant and I have upvoted it.

Comment: @alec_djinn Knowingly using a function that exposes a huge attack surface when a  safe and easy alternative is available (`getattr` in this case) is a very questionable decision.

Comment: @alec_djinn I usally try to avoid `eval`. Even if my solution is save in this case maybe later some other developer might change or remove my choices which makes `eval` a risk in future releases. Second the `getattr` seems not so finicky about single or double quotes as the `eval` does. `getattr` is in all points the better alternative.

Comment: I find the comment about the "attack surface" much more relevant than the reason given in the answer. The shown `eval` usage with validated input looks safe, but once you have the `eval` in the code base and forget about it several commits later, bad things can happen ...

Comment: @VPfB Thanks for the input. I've incorporated my comment in the answer